# SQL numbering with different Code restarted

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have different code for each record. Let say: S, W, I

So, when first record is created for code S. The Id column should be `S001`, next `S002`. Then if there's a new record for W, it will be started from 001. So the Id would be W001 and so on.

How can I create this type of ID? The table looks like:

```
Id    GroupCode   Address
---------------------------
S001  S           Brisbane
```

Ff.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using several `SEQUENCE`s.

Comment: What happens when you get to `'S999'`?

Comment: What happens to 'S002' when 'S001' is deleted?

Comment: @Larnu, the next number would be S1000

Comment: @SMor, It stays as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       concat(group_code,
              format(row_number() over (partition by group_code order by (select null)), '0000')
             ) as new_id
from t;
```

Note that your table has not specified an ordering, so the assignment of values is arbitrary.